# asp.net accessing javascript variables after ajax updatepanel

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm using AJAX on an ASP.NET web project to update a page.  Some of my functions return XML that I want to embed on the page after it reloads.  This part works, here's a sample of how it looks at the top of the page:

```
var productXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><ArrayOfProduct xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><Product><ActualProdID>123</ActualProdID><Name>Test</Name><Description>Test</Description><Edition>Test</Edition><Platform>Test</Platform><Family>Test</Family><Type>Test</Type><DeploymentTypes>Test</DeploymentTypes><BaseActualProdID>Test</BaseActualProdID><Price>0</Price></Product></ArrayOfProduct>";
```

Later in the page I'm trying to use the XML but it's not working.  I tried to do something simple and just throw an alert box in that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function closeLoading()
{
    jQuery('.pleaseWaitPanel').css({ 'display': 'none', 'visibility': 'hidden' });
    alert("here");
    alert(productXML);
    alert("here2");
}
</script>
```

closeLoading() is called inside:

```
window.onload = function () { Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(closeLoading); };
```

It loads the jQuery and the first alert "here" works perfect.  When I go to alert the productXML, nothing happens.  It doesn't throw a JavaScript error, I'm using Firebug.  I can confirm the XML is on the page.

Any help on this would be GREATLY appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code snippets, it looks like your `closeLoading` function is only being called in your `window.onload` function. This means that it *won't* be called after any Ajax request completes as the window won't be reloaded.

I would try moving your call to `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(closeLoading)` to just before your closing server-side form tag:

```
<form runat="server">
    ...
    <script>
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(closeLoading);
    </script>
</form>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var productXML
```

Is a ServerSide variable, so you don't have access to this in Client script.

If you want to use in a javascript function you can do this :

1) Put the result in a textbox hidden, like

```
<input type='hidden' value='<%=productXML%>'>
```

then simply get the value of the textbox.

Comment: It's not server side, that's the javascript var I'm embedding on the page.  It *should* be accessible client side since it does show up between <script type="text/javascript">var productXml="";</script>

Comment: Sorry.... 
I've tried your code (only the var declaration and the alert) and i see the alert... try to put the var declaration inside your function and see if it show up the alert.